# Using a Module? w/ nodeJS

Tags: javascript, module

I've added the link to the external file containing the following code.  What would I put in the body to make this code work?
Thanks a lot!

```
module.exports = {

clickEvent: function() {
var calEvent = $('.fc-time-grid-event')[0];
var calEventStart = $(calEvent).find('.fc-time').attr('data-start');
$(calEvent).click();
return calEventStart;
},
fillSubmit: function() {
var data = {
name: 'Joe Test',
email: 'test@timekit.io',
comment: 'This is a test'
};
$('.input-name').val(data.name);
$('.input-email').val(data.email);
$('.input-comment').val(data.comment);
$('.bookingjs-form-button').click();
return data;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using nodeJS?

Comment: I think that module.export is nodeJS code.

Comment: @MaxMastalerz Yes, nodeJS

Comment: @MaxMastalerz I didn't write it, just implementing on our site.  My knowledge of jQuery is elementary.  Is this not a good idea or not possible?

Comment: `var myModule = require('./filename.js');` the functions in the code are then accessible via `myModule.functionNameHere()` It doesn't make sense to have jQuery on the server-side.